# How to make href="#" work like a submit button in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, href, isset

I have a table where I would like to click the contents and then show a new table below it on the same Wordpress Pluggin Admin page with its content details (created by my PHP function pop_details() where I am passing the href value as reference), like Oracle child forms.

Unfortunately, my code is not working (nothing happens when I click the href link but the rest of the buttons are working), I am a purist when it comes to code :D so I don't want a submit button with transparent background to do this (besides it is really nicer this way) so if you can help me, I will surely appreciate it. Thank you.

Table details:

```
...
echo "<td><a href='#' name='order_selected' value='".$myData->orderid."'>"
.$myData->orderid."</td>";
...
```

ISSET:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['order_selected']))
    {
        $myOrderSel = $_GET['order_selected'];
        pop_details($myOrderSel);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you style the submit button as link with CSS or use javascript. For example jQuery form.submit() function?

Comment: Please, pay attention on this. Due to the fact that `name` attribute under the `<a>` tag is an anchor name (deprecated, `id` is using now) not a post/get stuff, use to set a hidden input with a small JS tweks to perform onCLick submit with your `<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have to use `<form>` with hidden element if you wan't to retrieve some POST values using static method...

2) Otherwise, you can use an Ajax call using Jquery for example like this :

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
   url : $(this).attr('href'),
   data : {$(this).attr('name') : $(this).attr('value')}
   });
});
```

3) Or you can use GET values by using the href like this :

```
"<a href='#?order_selected = ".$myData->orderid."' name='order_selected' value='".$myData->orderid."'>"
```

And retrieve it in PHP with :

```
isset($_GET['order_selected'])
```

**To be clear**

This PHP code works :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['test'])) {
      exit($_GET['test']);
  }
  echo "<a href='?test=mytest'>This is my test</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Hi @JoDev, thank you for the response and I have modified my code as you suggested. However, I wonder why it is still not working even if I added an echo statement and it is not even passing the isset condition, I have pasted the entire code as follows if you have time:

Comment: Sorry that looks awful:

Comment: Can you update your first post with your new code, to be able to see what are you doing now! (don't hesitate to create a [fiddle](www.jsfiddle.net) )

Comment: Guys I really appreciate the effort but I tried all the suggestions and it is still not working. Please kindly email me geobgs@gmail.com so I can send you the php file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I will create a fiddle, please hold on brother.

Comment: Hi JoDev, it is my first time in fiddle, but I could not see the PHP option. I will try and create a dummy link in one of my sites so you can be able to see the text version of the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You simply have to remove the `#` in the href! Or (better) add the current URL! And it will work!

Comment: For information, I was wrong, jsfiddle doesn't allow you to use PHP... sorry!

Comment: Just click on the image to get a full view [link](http://healeddiabetics.com/my-code/?preview=true&preview_id=15&preview_nonce=16722f70b5)<-CLick here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I assume that you have `<form>` tag in your html code

**data-value**='".$myData->orderid."

```
echo "<td><a href='#' name='order_selected' data-value='".$myData->orderid."'>"
.$myData->orderid."</td>";

$('a').click(function() {
    var url = <FILE_NAME>; /*filename where you want to submit the data*/
    $.post(url+"?order_selected="+$(this).data('value'),
        $('form').serializeArray(),
        function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Hi @Mangesh Parte and others, thank you for your response, but I think I am missing out somthing, I have tried all of your suggestions but here is the compressed script:

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
$('a').click(function() {
    var url = <createpo.php>; /*filename where you want to submit the data*/
    $.post(url+"?order_selected="+$(this).data('value'),
        $('form').serializeArray(),
        function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    );
});
</script>

...

<form method=POST action='' name=form>
...

Comment: <tbody>
<?php
...
echo "<tr>";  
...
echo "<td><a href='#?order_selected = ".$myData->orderid."' name='order_selected' value='".$myData->orderid."'>".$myData->orderid."</td>";
...
echo "</tr>";
?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['order_selected']))
 {
  echo "I am here";
  $myOrderSel = $_GET['order_selected'];
  pop_details($myOrderSel);
 }
?>
</form>

Comment: @LogicMaster replace this line `var url = <createpo.php>; ` with `var url = 'createpo.php'; `

Answer (score 0):

I think I am giving up this post since all of your answers are right however I feel that my SSL and site security is the one preventing me on running the scripts and I am ending up seeing no permission pages. But, I would like to thank for the efforts. You are great everyone :D